# Breadcrumbs and Structured Data, without a visible > on the page, plus nesting options

Tags: microdata, schema.org, structured-data, breadcrumbs

When I add breadcrumbs soon (with microdata) - do I need to write

**link1 > link2 > link3** (as in the google example code) 
in the visible text on the page, or will

**link1  link2  link3** without the **>** symbol still appear like this in the search results

Books **>** Poetry **>** Modern Poetry

If it must be included can I somehow mark the **>** symbol as *not visible/hidden* using CSS?

See [example website](https://ludwig.im/en/projects/html5-and-schema.org-seo-best-practices-for-microdata) not showing the `>` but using breadcrumbs that do, without `>` in the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the `>`symbol regarding to the Google Structured Data page about [Breadcrumbs](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/breadcrumbs).

Just use a markup as shown in the example:

```
<ol itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/arts">
            <span itemprop="name">Arts</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
        <a itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/arts/books">
            <span itemprop="name">Books</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ol>
```

Google will then insert the `>` in the search results by it's own.

If you *want* to use a separator just place them in raw `<li></li>` elements without the itemprop markup.

Comment: Regarding your edit: Note that having text (like a separator) in an `ol`  element is not allowed, so it has to be part of the `li` elements.

Comment: @unor yes you are right. Updating the post.